# How to trigger a ticket on kibanahud from python code

Tags: python, curl, elasticsearch, kibana

I am stuck at a problem
What I want to do is once a certain threshold is reached I want to trigger a ticket on KibanaHud from my python code.

I am creating a json file with all the data that I need for the ticket -> ticket.json

I am also using curl Xpost to create index

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/ticket_tweet/' -d '
index:
  number_of_shards: 5
  number_of_replicas: 2
'
```

and then doing

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/ticket_tweet/rook_ticket -d @ticket.json
```

but getting error :

> {"error":"UnavailableShardsException[[ticket_tweet][3] Not enough
>   active copies to meet write consistency of [QUORUM] (have 1, needed
>   2). Timeout: [1m], request: index
>   {[ticket_tweet][rook_ticket][AU2zD8QRdqkd3i74WG-f]

Comment: can someone help me out with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was of shards....i did some hit and try for the value of shards (since mapping was not available) and the problem got solved. if anyone has a better solution please provide